# What's the best way to create a UML element in javafx 8.0?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a UML Editor using JavaFX, and I'd need to add to the scene UML elements such as a Actor, Process, Class, etc. These elements need to be selectable, resizable, their color and font changeable.

I've been looking at the JavaFX specification, I've found some possible solutions, but the documentation seems shallow on custom controls and shapes.

My idea is to simply add these components to the scene:

```
// Simplified code
public ClassController {
  @FXML
  private Pane editorPane;

  // this would be called by an event
  public addClass(int x, int y, UMLClass umlClass) {
    // either a Control, Shape or Path
    UMLClassComponent umlClassCp = new UMLClassComponent(x, y, umlClass);
    editorPane.getChildren().add(umlClassCp);
  }
}
```

I am considering either:

- Create a custom [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html). Yet, subclassing Shape doesn't seem to be a simple task, and I can't find any indication on how to do this. I've been looking at Rectangle and other shapes, but I don't know the Shape Architecture...
- Use Path to draw the components, like it's shown [here](https://glyphsoft.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/javafx-2-custom-shapes/). I could add some MoveTo, LineTo PathElements to create the UML Elements I need. This seems less than ideal, since it'd be quite verbose.
- Subclass [Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html), define a Skin with SkinBase and Behavior with BehaviorBase. This feels like a good solution, and I've found quite some documentation and how-tos on it. Yet, can I think of my UML elements as controls? Subclassing Control seems to be considered overkill if they're only going to be used by one application. Besides, as of JavaFX 8, BehaviorBase is still private.

Comment: Just keep it simple, use labels or a region subclass like a StackPane styled with and a svgpath based [`-fx-shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).  Develop the rest of your app using that basic concept for your url widgets and, once your app is more complete, you will have a much better understanding of JavaFX development and, if necessary, be able to modify the basic UML widgets as you need then.  Google how to create [svgpath strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) for your shapes in a drawing app.

Comment: My comment above is just a getting started suggestion.  Creating fully functional UML elements in an interactive graphic editor is a complex and difficult task.  I did some googling for a free library of SVG based symbols for UML, and didn't come up with much, so, unfortunately, I don't think my SVG path based suggestion will be of much use to you.

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2724651) which demonstrates some of the dragging, resizing and color change aspects you mention in your question, though it is just labels and by no means full UML diagrams.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion proved useful, I've been able to create a proof-of-concept class diagram subclassing Group and using Path (which is basically a svg-path where each PathElement - MoveTo, LineTo, etc - corresponds to a Node) + Text elements. I'll try to achieve the same subclassing Control, then Shape.